# Como faço Imprimir resultado de uma Parse.Query numa View?

Tags: angularjs

Eu tenho a seguinte situação, na `View`:

> `{{nomeCraque}}`

e no `Angular`:

```
$scope.nomeCraque = {};
var EscalacaoObject = Parse.Object.extend("Escalacao");
var query = new Parse.Query(EscalacaoObject);
query.find({   
          success: function(results) {
          // Successfully retrieved the object.

          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var object = results[i];
            $scope.nomeCraque = object.get("nomeCraque");
          }

        },
        error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
  })
```

Desta forma `$scope.nomeCraque` imprime `{}` na `View`, como faço para imprimir na `View`o resultado correto que a `Query` está retornando?

Comment: `console.log(object.get("nomeCraque"));` mostra o quê?

Comment: Mostra o dado correto retornado pela Parse.Query.

Comment: $scope.nomeCraque = { nome: 'nomeInicial' }; , na view {{nomeCraque.nome}}, depois é só atribuir o valor abrindo o $scope

Comment: Felipe, bom dia! desculpe mas não entendi quando você diz: "atribuir o valor abrindo o $scope", como eu devo fazer para atribuir o valor retornado da Parse.Query a variável $scope.nomeCraque ?

Comment: $scope.nomeCraque = { nome: object.get("nomeCraque"); }

Comment: pode ser que resolva seu problema

Comment: Felipe, não sei se fiz algo errado, segue trecho do angular ...      

Inicie com  $scope.nomeCraque = { nome: 'nomeInicial' }; ... 

Fiz atribuição de valor como $scope.nomeCraque = { nome: object.get("nomeCraque") } ; 
Pois da forma como você escreveu, $scope.nomeCraque = { nome: object.get("nomeCraque"); } provoca erro de sintaxe ao salvar o código: " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;"

Mas, infelizmente ainda não deu certo, pois na view ficou assim: {"nome":""} 

 DETALHE, no console.log fica assim:  Object {nome: nometeste}

Tem ideia do porquê?

Comment: @Ita na atribuição você não pode fechar a query com ponto e virgula, deixe sem nada ou finalize com uma vírgula

Comment: Ok Felipe, entendi, mas independente deste detalhe, o problema persiste e na view eu não consigo obter o resultado retornado pelo Parse.Query, será que está faltando mais algum procedimento a ser feito?

Answer (score 0):

Felipe, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda até o momento, nesta parte final eu descobri o que estava faltando, segue abaixo o tratamento que fiz no meu código angular: $scope.nomeCraque = { nome: object.get("nomeCraque") };
$scope.$apply();
AGORA ESTÁ FUNCIONANDO CONFORME EU DESEJAVA!, OU SEJA, O RESULTADO DA PARSE.QUERY ESTÁ SENDO EXIBIDO NA VIEW! Obrigado a todos pelo apoio!